# How to retrieve id in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I can retrieve other details of user except id. It displays null value in frontend page..

```
<tbody>
  @foreach($users as $row)
     <tr>
       <td>{{$row->id}}</td>
       <td>{{$row->name}}</td>
       <td>{{$row->username}}</td>
       <td>{{$row->email}}</td>
       <td>{{$row->usertype}}</td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

create_users_table.php

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('usertype');
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: what's your `create_users_table.php` file looks like.

Comment: that's weird, do you still get null value on the controller part. like what happens id you do `dd($users)` in your controller?

Comment: Can you add the screenshot of your table data?

Comment: @AndySong  Thank you for enlighten me. I have found the solution. I missed the id in controller.

Comment: @all Thank you you all for trying to help me. I have found the solution. Thank you.